# How to set UIImageView into fullscreen when device rotates?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to set my UIImage into fullscreen when the device rotates. The problem is that the imageView doesn't rotate properly (it isn't in fullscreen). Currently, I have that piece of code:
I add this to the viewDidLoad() function: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rotate), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)` 
and that is my method:

```
func rotate() {
    self.contentView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.imageView?.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Does your imageView not go full screen, or does the image not fill the whole imageView? You might want to inspect the frame of the imageView, and if it actually matches your self.view.bounds, set the contentMode of the imageView to aspectFill

Comment: working on it.. please wait

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might help you, in **Swift 2**(leave your notification center observer as it is):

### Set it to full screen:

```
func rotate(){

        let SizeOfScreen: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let HeightOfScreen = SizeOfScreen.height
        let WidthOfScreen = SizeOfScreen.width
        yourImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: WidthOfScreen, height: HeightOfScreen)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overcomplicating this a bit. Rather than worry about KVO, the way I would do this is to override the viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator method for your UIImageView's view controller (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/).

This method is called automatically when a view controller's root view changes size - which includes rotation of the device, and those calls are propagated down the view controller hierarchy. The method will give you the size of the view as a parameter which you can then use to resize your image.

To ensure the image resizes, by the way, you must also ensure that the contentMode of the UIImageView is set to UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill, Or .scaleAspectFill to make sure it fills its frame. I also see that you can select UIViewContentMode.redraw, which automatically calls setNeedsDisplay() when the view's bounds change. Hope that helps.